# XML writer and Memory Stream c#

Tags: c#, memorystream, xmlwriter

I am creating a file using XmlWriter, `XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileName);` it is creating a file and then i have one more function which i am calling  `private void EncryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)` which takes 2 string input and outpulfile and in the end i have two files one is encrypted and one is not. I just want one encrypted file but foor my encrypt function it takes inputfile which is created by XmlWriter. Is there any way i can create memorystream and pass that into my function instead of creating a inputfile.
  my encrypt function

```
private void EncryptFile (string inputFile, string outputFile)
            string password = @"fdds"; // Your Key Here
            UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();

            byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);
            string cryptFile = outputFile;
            FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create);

            RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();


            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key,key),CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

            int data;
            while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
                cs.WriteByte((byte)data);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
            fsIn.Close();
            cs.Close();
            fsCrypt.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create an `XmlWriter` that writes to a memory stream:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream);
```

Now you can pass this stream to your `EncryptFile` function instead of an `inputFile`. You have to make sure that you don't forget these two things before reading the stream:

1. Make a call to `writer.Flush()` when you are done writing.
2. Set `stream.Position` back to `0` before you start reading the stream.

Comment: writer.Flush() was what I was missing.  Thx.